# Issues with Saving Dynamic Metabox

Tags: metabox

So I'm having issues regarding a Dynamic Todo List Metabox.
It should be so simple, everything else is working except for saving. I've been looking at it for 5 hours now, and could do with some fresh eyes.

```
    function webm_todo_box(){
    global $post;
    ?>
    <div id="meta_inner">
    <?php

    //get the saved meta as an arry
    $TodoList = get_post_meta($post->ID,'TodoList');

    $c = 0;
    if ( is_array($TodoList) ) {
        foreach( $TodoList as $Todo ) {
            if ( isset( $TodoList['todotitle'] ) ) {
                printf( '<p>Todo Item Title: <input type="text" name="TodoList[%1$s][todotitle]" value="%2$s" /><span class="remove">%4$s</span></p>', $c, $TodoList['todotitle'], __( 'Remove Track' ) );
                $c = $c +1;
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
<span id="here"></span>
<span class="add"><?php _e('Add Todo Item'); ?></span>
<script>
    var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var count = <?php echo $c; ?>;
        $(".add").click(function() {
            count = count + 1;

            $('#here').append('<p>Todo Item Title: <input type="text" name="TodoList['+count+'][todotitle]" value="" /><span class="remove">Remove Track</span></p>' );
            return false;
        });
        $(".remove").live('click', function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
    </script>
</div><?php

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_TodoList', 10, 2 );
/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function save_TodoList( $post_id ) {
    // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

    $TodoList = $_POST['todotitle'];


    update_post_meta($post_id,'todotitle', $TodoList);
}
```

Comment: Can you please recheck the code you have pasted? `save_TodoList` function is missing

Comment: Sure, oh my apologies :)

Comment: Code updated :)

Answer (score 0):

I too have come across this strange issue, I am not sure why `$post_id` doesn't contain the post id. Please try the below snippet and this would work

Use the `global $post` and use `$post->ID` in `update_post_meta`

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_TodoList' );
/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function save_TodoList() {
    global $post;

    // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

    $TodoList = $_POST['todotitle'];

    update_post_meta($post->ID,'todotitle', $TodoList); 
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working. :(

Comment: Are you sure of getting the value of `$TodoList`?

Comment: I'm not sure, is there a way I can test?

Comment: Yes you can, but before that can you test my code with taking off the following from the snippet **if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;**

Comment: I've had that line in with every test I've made. I've also tested without, same thing.

Comment: Can you check the console for any jquery errors as I see you are using `.live()` which is no more supported by the latest Jquery

Comment: Hm, can check yep. Seems no issues with JQuery, I'm only using .live() for removing the boxes. And that seems to work too :)

Comment: You are using this `$TodoList = $_POST['todotitle'];` to get the value, can you check with the input field it seems you are not getting the value

Comment: Apologies I'm going on my 25th hour without sleep, how do I do that? :p

Comment: I've echoed todotitle and it's coming out blank.

Comment: FYI [`wp_is_post_autosave()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_is_post_autosave/) is a shorter variant of that. [`wp_is_post_revision()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_is_post_revision/) is a similar, neighboring check.

Answer (score 0):

In your input field the name attribute is "**TodoList…**"
I would say "**$_POST['todotitle']**" is just empty

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_TodoList', 10, 2 );
/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function save_TodoList( $post_id ) {
    // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

    $TodoList = $_POST['todotitle'];

    update_post_meta($post_id,'todotitle', $TodoList);

    # DEBUG START
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $_POST, TRUE ) . '</pre>';
    die('---end---');
    # DEBUG END
}
```

Debug first what you are doing.

1. Check if the function is actually called
2. Check if you pass the 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' clause
3. Check if your $_POST var is set
4. Check if the var contain the data you expect
5. Save the data

Comment: Didn't know you could print out the full array, handy Debugging feature. It's told me that the [todotitle] => 1234, which is what I've set it to, it's just not updating the boxes back on the post.

Comment: It's also printing out to the single template, so there's an issue with the update_post_meta then?

Comment: Sorry for the treble comment, starting to resolve this now, it's an issue with my foreach loop, rather than instantiating todotitle it's setting todotitle to be the last entry from the last box.